# Problems to start drawing an energy landscape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a diagram as depicted below.

The colors, dotted lines, circles etc are not important.

Ideally, the number of plots behind each other should be easily adaptable and the "shape" of the curve parametrized, eg being a formula rather than hardcoded.

Specifically, my problem is in finding the right "function" that draws a curve with 1 or two holes as depicted and how to place them behind each other.

**Edit: Current MWE provided below.**

[image]

Here is my current MWE. I'm quite ashamed of where I'm stuck.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns,decorations.pathreplacing, positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{ballshading}{\pgfpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}
 {color(0bp)=(gray!40!white); 
 color(9bp)=(gray!75!white);
 color(18bp)=(gray!70!black); 
 color(25bp)=(gray!50!black); 
 color(50bp)=(black)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[restrict y to domain=-5:9.9, 
    %axis lines=none
    ]
    \addplot[red,domain=-5:2*pi, samples=200, name path = A]{sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red,domain=-5:2*pi, samples=200]{sin(deg(x))+1};
    \addplot[red,domain=-5:2*pi, samples=200]{sin(deg(x))+2};

    \pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{sin(deg(-5))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{sin(deg(5))}

        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{2.1cm}{4cm}}{0.25cm}
  \pgfshadepath{ballshading}{20}
  \pgfusepath{}

    \addplot[name path=B, color=black, thick] coordinates {(-5.01,\valueA) (-5,-1.5) (5, -1.5) (5, \valueB-0.05)};
    \addplot[color=red!10] fill between[of=B and A], soft clip={domain=-5:5}];


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following result:

[image]

Multiple problems remain.

1. How can I translate the plots on the x-axis?
2. How can I properly draw the fill between ? There's a small part betweem 5:6 which is colored in red still
3. The ball seems to vanish if it's plotted in the "fill" area
4. What variation of sin or sinc could help me produce a more "random" landscape?

Comment: Pleas do show us what you have, you basically ask us to start a new document and start from scratch. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since you mention a specific problem concerning making the curve with holes etc., you presumably have code which goes someway towards that e.g. making the curve without the holes or making the blue block without the curve. Post what you have.

Comment: @cfr I put my current progress. It's not much though, I'm still at a loss on how tikz "thinks". At least I have the starting blocks in the MWE I believe. Thanks for any hints, which don't need to be a full solution.

Comment: I would recommend you post separate questions instead of just one question. That way they could be helpful to others as well as opposed to this specific example that you are trying to accomplish. A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that is focused on each of the 4 sub-questions you have above should be provided, with any items not related to that _one_ specific question removed.

Comment: Hi Peter. You're right, I figured there would be less "small" problems to solve initially :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `pgfplots` is not adequate for this kind of graphic. You can use standard `tikz` and the `plot` object as part of a path.

The following code shows a possible way to do it. I don't like how the coordinates of each plot are "manually" specified, but it was not too hard to do. I used `scopes` to shift each case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{myblue}{cyan!70!blue!80!black}
\colorlet{myball}{orange}

\begin{tikzpicture}
{[xshift=-0cm, yshift=-0cm]
  \draw[fill=myblue!60] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- plot[smooth, tension=0.6] coordinates {(0,1)   (1,0.5)  (3,1)   (6,2)} -- (6,0) --cycle; 
  \shade[ball color=myball] (1,0.7) circle (0.2);
}

{[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-1.1cm]
  \draw[fill=myblue!70] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) -- plot[smooth, tension=0.6] coordinates {(0,1.5)   (1,0.5)  (3,1.2)   (5,1.2)   (6,2)} -- (6,0) --cycle; 
  \shade[ball color=myball!30] (1,0.7) circle (0.2);
  \shade[ball color=myball] (4.8,1.4) circle (0.2);
}

{[xshift=-1cm, yshift=-2.2cm]
  \draw[fill=myblue!80] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- plot[smooth, tension=0.6] coordinates {(0,2)   (1,0.7)  (3,1.2)   (5,1.0)   (6,2)} -- (6,0) --cycle;
  \shade[ball color=myball!30] (1.1,0.9) circle (0.2);
  \shade[ball color=myball] (4.8,1.2) circle (0.2);
}

{[xshift=-1.5cm, yshift=-3.3cm]
  \draw[fill=myblue!90] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- plot[smooth, tension=0.6] coordinates {(0,2)   (1,1)  (3,1.2)   (5,0.8)   (6,2)} -- (6,0) --cycle; 
  \shade[ball color=myball!30] (1.1,1.18) circle (0.2);
  \shade[ball color=myball] (4.8,1.0) circle (0.2);
}

{[xshift=-2cm, yshift=-4.4cm]
  \draw[fill=myblue] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- plot[smooth, tension=0.6] coordinates {(0,2)   (1,1.3)  (3,1.5)   (5,0.5)   (6,2)} -- (6,0) --cycle; 
  \shade[ball color=myball!30] (1.1,1.5) circle (0.2);
  \shade[ball color=myball] (4.9,0.7) circle (0.2);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Fantastic. The `smooth` with the `tension` answered my first question. The xshift the remainder. Thanks a lot!